# Show video thumbnail without loading the video

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is it possible to show thumbnail from a video without having to load the video? I don't need the video to play, just want to show a thumbnail.

I want to show the thumbnail after uploading the video using fileupload. And the thumbnail needs to come from the video.

All on localhost.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried and looked up? Where are you planning on using this? Where are the videos from? You need to be more descriptive of your problem.

Comment: if the video stream site don't give you ready made thumbnail - you cant show thumbnail without grab the video....   you  need to create the small pics by you own... and connect the, to the right IMG tag

Comment: just on localhost - All I read was about using poster but that requires the video to load. I plan to display the thumbnail after uploading the video with fileupload.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is setting preload to metadata

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

```html
<video
  preload='metadata' 
  style="width:400px; height:auto;"
  src='https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm' 
/>
```

Comment: this seems like the best solution?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can specify not to preload the video with `preload="none"`. You can specify the thumbnail with `poster="<url of image>"`. More options on [the docs of `<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

```html
<h1>Default</h1>
<video controls width="200">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<h1>With poster + preload="none"</h1>
<video controls width="200" preload="none" poster="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Bear_Alaska_%283%29.jpg">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I don't actually have a picture of the thumbnail - I need the thumbnail to come from the video I am uploading using fileupload.

Comment: Then don't use the poster tag. The poster (what you call thumbnail) will be automatically loaded while using the fewer data possible.

Comment: Problem is when I set preload to 'none' it won't load anything as a poster(thumbnail) - https://imgur.com/a/wF8n6q5

Comment: That solved my issue but I am loading the video in iframe with youtube link as a soruce. Good solution if you have a lot of videos added to your page because it lowers the loading time of the page drastically. Thanks @NinoFiliu !

Answer (score 1):

You can install the npm: `video-metadata-thumbnails`, then use it like this:

```
import { getMetadata, getThumbnails } from 'video-metadata-thumbnails';

const thumbnails = await getThumbnails(blob, {
  interval: 1,
  start: 0,
  end: 0
});
console.log('Preview: ', thumbnails[0]);
```

Example: https://www.ellow.cn/examples/video-metadata-thumbnails/index.html