# Don't preload video, but still show "thumbnail"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video

I'm trying to display many video thumbnails/posters without actually loading the video...

Bascially what I've got is the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="padding: 20px;" onclick='location.href="/videoDetails/{{ @video.ID }}"'>
      <video width="100%" style="cursor:pointer;"
          <source src="/{{ @video.path }}">
           Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
</div>
```

That hole thing is in a `foreach` loop and with that, it loads up to 100 videos on one page...

My problem now is that this gets super slow, the more videos there are load at once..

Now I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54634175/3375021) answer on a StackOverflow thread, where it says to use the attribute `preload="none"` on the video tag... That seems to speed up the loading (because it doesn't preload the videos), however, it doesn't display any image (preview) at all..

In my case, there's no reason to load the hole video though, because (as you can see in the code), the actual video is then displayed on another page, when clicking on the `div`.

Also, just to make sure you got me right, I want to display the auto generated preview of the first frame of the video. I can't upload a seperate image to display it with the `poster` attribute, it has to be the default image..

Is there any way I can achieve this? I'm also open to Javascript/jQuery solutions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get video frames in different time periods with append `#t` in the video source url. But with the attribute `preload` `none` value you cannot get the video frames. So You need to use the `metadata` value in the `preload` attribute.
These are the three values you can use in the `preload` attribute:

**none** - Hints to the browser that the user likely will not watch the video, or that minimizing unnecessary traffic is desirable.

**metadata** - Hints to the browser that the user is not expected to need the video, but that fetching its metadata (dimensions, first frame, tracklist, duration, and so on) is desirable.

**auto** - Hints to the browser that optimistically downloading the entire video is considered desirable. - Hints to the browser that optimistically downloading the entire video are considered desirable.

You can check the below results with these three values.

```html
<p>metadata</p>
<video width="300" height="150" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
   <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4#t=2" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<p>none</p>
<video width="300" height="150" controls="controls" preload="none">
   <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4#t=2" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<p>auto</p>
<video width="300" height="150" controls="controls" preload="auto">
   <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4#t=2" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: does this logic work on other extensions other than mp4 like avi etc? on avi its not working in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that creating so many video HTML elements will affect performance anyhow, loading or not, since the DOM is under quite heavy pressure.
A different (and more advance) approach I would recommend is the following.

If you want that one image will load when the user clicks on it, you can "create" a video in that specific moment, triggering only the video requested.
So:

1. instead of the video tag, load an image with onclick listener, that will pass an ID to a JS function
2. when the user clicks it will create the video element.
3. at the same time, hide the image (or maybe a gif?)

Try to run the snippet here below :)

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  var videlem = document.createElement("video");
    element.innerHTML = '';
  source = 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4';
  var sourceMP4 = document.createElement("source"); 
  sourceMP4.type = "video/mp4";
  sourceMP4.src = source;
  videlem.appendChild(sourceMP4);
  videlem.autoplay = true;
  element.appendChild(videlem);
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the image</p>
<div id="img242">
  <img onclick="myFunction('img242')" src="https://blog.majestic.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Video-Icon-crop.png">
</div>
```

Comment: In general, this is a nice approach, so I would not need to even load metadata of the video, like @Amit Saini suggested... However, as mentioned, unfortunatelly I don't have the preview images for the videos, so it would need to be the first frame of the video instead of a "regular" image...

Comment: To get an image from the video, you can use VLC.  Open the video in VLC and run it to the frame you want to use for your image.  Pause the video, then choose the Video->Take Snapshot menu option.  This save the image to the root or your Pictures folder on Windows.  Not sure where it goes on the Mac